# Inject EntityManager within ConstraintValidator

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

Hello I want to inject **EntityManager** within **ConstraintValidator**

This is my codes

**CoreConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
public class CoreConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public  MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
        MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor = new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
        methodValidationPostProcessor.setValidator(validator());

        return methodValidationPostProcessor;
    }

    @Bean(name="validator")
    public static LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();


        /* * ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new
         * ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
         * messageSource.setBasename("/WEB-INF/messages/validation");
         * localValidatorFactoryBean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource);*/

        return localValidatorFactoryBean;
    }

}
```

**UniqueKeyValidator.java**

In this class I try to inject the EntityManager, but it always gives null

```
@Component
public class UniqueKeyValidator implements
        ConstraintValidator<Unique, Serializable> {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private Class<?> entityClass;
    private String uniqueField;

    public void initialize(Unique unique) {
        entityClass = unique.entity();
        uniqueField = unique.property();
    }

    @Transactional
    public boolean isValid(Serializable property,
            ConstraintValidatorContext cvContext) {

        String query = String.format("from %s where %s = :val ",entityClass.getName(), uniqueField);
        List<?> list = entityManager.createQuery(query).setParameter("val", property).getResultList();

        return list != null && list.size() > 0;
    }


}
```

When I test the code, the **EntityManager** always gives null.

Answer (score 1):

You created the `UniqueKeyValidator` using its constructor (`new UniqueKeyValidator()`) instead of injecting it (using Spring DI) into your test class.

The CoreConfiguration doesn't contain this validator anyway, so probably Spring doesn't scan it at all. All `@Component` classes must have a `component:scan` too.